# How to communicate with ATTiny85/Digispark via USB on PC?

Tags: c++, arduino, attiny

Recently I'm trying to make a simple LED controller with ATTiny85/Digispark.

I tried to use `DigiCDC` lib to perform data IO
but it does not work on my PC (win10 x64).

test code:

```cpp
#include <DigiCDC.h>

void setup()
{
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);

  SerialUSB.begin();
  SerialUSB.println("hello world");
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  delay(800);
  
  SerialUSB.println("ping");
  int ava = SerialUSB.available();
  int buffer[ava];

  // read buffer
  for(int step = 0; step < ava; step++)
    buffer[step] = SerialUSB.read();
  // write buffer back
  for(int step = 0; step < ava; step++)
    SerialUSB.print(buffer[step]);
  SerialUSB.println("==line end==");
  delete buffer;
}
```

Official demo [mentioned here](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/digicdc) (Arduino IDE - Files - Examples - DigiCDC - Echo) also did not work.

Once program is compiled and uploaded onto board, Windows shows a "Unknown USB device" notification. And no usable serial port devices can be found.

- Are there missing some drivers?
- Or `DigiCDC` lib is simply not working on Win10?
- Or I should use another lib to achieve communication between PC and ATTiny85/Digispark via USB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DigiKeyboard library to send key strokes. I'd recommend [Danjovic's fork](https://github.com/Danjovic/DigistumpArduino/tree/master) because it also allows you to [check the status of the caps lock, num lock and scroll lock keys](https://hackaday.io/page/6947-digikeyboard-with-leds).

Here's the sample code that comes with DigiKeyboard library:

```
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

void setup() {
  // don't need to set anything up to use DigiKeyboard
}


void loop() {
  // this is generally not necessary but with some older systems it seems to
  // prevent missing the first character after a delay:
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
  
  // Type out this string letter by letter on the computer (assumes US-style
  // keyboard)
  DigiKeyboard.println("Hello Digispark!");
  
  // It's better to use DigiKeyboard.delay() over the regular Arduino delay()
  // if doing keyboard stuff because it keeps talking to the computer to make
  // sure the computer knows the keyboard is alive and connected
  DigiKeyboard.delay(5000);
}
```